# How to subclass XMLParser (or TreeBuilder) in Python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, elementtree

I have been searching for the answer to this for days. All of the examples of creating custom XML parsers that I can find (e.g. in the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html), or [this example](http://pymotw.com/2/xml/etree/ElementTree/parse.html), or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20574752/subclassing-elementtree-parser-to-retain-comments) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226386/parsing-xml-in-python-using-a-custom-element-class)) talk about generating entirely new data (e.g. the depth of the XML, or a CSV equivalent).

However, all I want to do is intercept the parsing, inspect the data, possibly alter it, then let the parser continue.

I tried this, as a toy example:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

class myParser():
  def start(self, tag, data):
    ##### Pretty sure this is wrong, but what should it be? #####
    return ET.XMLParser.start(tag, data)
  def data(self, data):
    return ET.XMLParser.data(data.replace('"', '&quot;'))
  def end(self, tag):
    return ET.XMLParser.end(tag)
  def close(self):
    return ET.XMLParser.close()

def parseFile(fileName):
  p = ET.XMLParser(target=myParser)
  tree = ET.parse(fileName, parser=p)
```

but I'm getting

`TypeError: 'unbound method start() must be called with myParser instance as first argument (got str instance instead)'`

I feel like I'm close, but I'm missing some vital piece of the puzzle that I just can't see.

Comment: You have defined the `start()` method twice in that class.  You should change the name of one of them.

Comment: Oops, that second one was meant to be `close()`. Copy-paste error : ( I'm not at that computer, so I'll have to try that when I get there this evening.

Comment: I fixed that problem (and another typo) and am still experiencing the same error.